# Getting a value from Javascript on Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rhtml

```
<td class="run_time"><%= l.text_field :run_time, :class => "line_item_run_time" %></td>
```

Hello.

I have rhtml code, l.text_field :run_time, has a value in its textbox that I need to use and I want to store it in a variable, if for example I do variable = l.text_field :run_time, it is going to save the whole object, the textbox with the value inside. Right now I just need the number that is inside.

Could you please tell me how can I do this it Ruby. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking for, but if you want the value from the object, what you might want is this:

```
variable = l.object.run_time
```

That calls the `run_time` method on the currently bound form object `l`.

Comment: Thank you Tadman. I am trying to get the value that is there. I am going to try with this but perhaps it only works with the java script. I wanted to pass this value from javascript to a variable in Ruby on rails but I think this is not possbile, any way, if this command gives me the value I think I can use it.

Comment: If you want to go from Ruby to JavaScript you need to send it back to the browser as a response. If you want to send it from JavaScript to Ruby you need to submit it as part of a request. This is just how HTTP works.

Answer (score 0):

If its a textfield, it would be part of a form, which you will eventually post to the server, sending to the server all the data for the fields in the form.
The call may be a redirect_call or an AJAX call, but the data would be sent to the server.
The action that you send the data to, will receive the data in a `params hash`, and then you can get the value of the text field.